# Python extension in C - Metaclass

Tags: python, c, inheritance, metaclass, python-extensions

I have the following python code:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # Only do checks for subclasses
        if cls.__name__ == 'Parent':
            return obj
        required_attrs = ['x']
        for ra in required_attrs:
            if ra not in dir(obj):
                fmt = 'Subclasses of Parent must define the %s attribute'
                raise NotImplementedError(fmt % ra)
        return obj

class Parent(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = True
```

`Meta` is used only to require that `Child` defines certain attributes. This class structure must remain as is because this is how my project is structured. `Parent` is actually called `DefaultConfig` and `Child` is actually a user-defined class derived from `DefaultConfig`.

I'm working on translating `Meta` and `Parent` into a C extension. This is the module:

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <structmember.h>

#define ARRLEN(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])


typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
} MetaObject;

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
} ParentObject;


static PyObject *Meta_call(MetaObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    PyObject *obj = PyType_GenericNew((PyTypeObject *) type, args, kwargs);

    // Only do checks for subclasses of Parent
    if (strcmp(obj->ob_type->tp_name, "Parent") == 0)
        return obj;

    // Get obj's attributes
    PyObject *obj_dir = PyObject_Dir(obj);
    if (obj_dir == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *required_attrs[] = {"x"};

    // Raise an exception of obj doesn't define all required_attrs
    PyObject *attr_obj;
    int has_attr;
    for (int i=0; i<ARRLEN(required_attrs); i++) {
        attr_obj = PyUnicode_FromString(required_attrs[i]);
        has_attr = PySequence_Contains(obj_dir, attr_obj);
        if (has_attr == 0) {
            printf("Subclasses of Parent must define %s\n", required_attrs[i]);
            // raise NotImplementedError
            return NULL;
        } else if (has_attr == -1) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}


static PyTypeObject MetaType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "custom.Meta",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(MetaObject),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
    .tp_new = PyType_GenericNew,
    .tp_call = (ternaryfunc) Meta_call,
};

static PyTypeObject ParentType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "custom.Parent",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(ParentObject),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
    .tp_new = PyType_GenericNew,
};


static PyModuleDef custommodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "custom",
    .m_size = -1,
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_custom(void) {
    PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&custommodule);
    if (module == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Should Parent inherit from Meta?
    ParentType.tp_base = &MetaType;

    if (PyType_Ready(&MetaType) < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(&MetaType);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "Meta", (PyObject *) &MetaType);

    if (PyType_Ready(&ParentType) < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(&ParentType);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "Parent", (PyObject *) &ParentType);

    return module;
}
```

This is the python code used to test module `custom`:

```py
import custom

class Child(custom.Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Child()
```

Unfortunately, there is no `.tp_meta` member in the `PyTypeObject` struct, so how do I specify `Meta` as the metaclass of `Parent`?

---

**EDIT**:

Modified C code:

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <structmember.h>

#define ARRLEN(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])


typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyTypeObject base;
} MetaObject;

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
} ParentObject;


static PyObject *Meta_call(MetaObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    PyObject *obj = PyType_GenericNew((PyTypeObject *) type, args, kwargs);

    // Only do checks for subclasses of Parent
    if (strcmp(obj->ob_type->tp_name, "Parent") == 0)
        return obj;

    // Get obj's attributes
    PyObject *obj_dir = PyObject_Dir(obj);
    if (obj_dir == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *required_attrs[] = {"x"};

    // Raise an exception of obj doesn't define all required_attrs
    PyObject *attr_obj;
    int has_attr;
    for (int i=0; i<ARRLEN(required_attrs); i++) {
        attr_obj = PyUnicode_FromString(required_attrs[i]);
        has_attr = PySequence_Contains(obj_dir, attr_obj);
        if (has_attr == 0) {
            printf("Subclasses of Parent must define %s\n", required_attrs[i]);
            // raise NotImplementedError
            return NULL;
        } else if (has_attr == -1) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}


static PyTypeObject MetaType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "custom.Meta",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(MetaObject),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
    .tp_new = PyType_GenericNew,
    .tp_call = (ternaryfunc) Meta_call,
};

static PyTypeObject ParentType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&MetaType, 0)
    .tp_name = "custom.Parent",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(ParentObject),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
    .tp_new = PyType_GenericNew,
};


static PyModuleDef custommodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    .m_name = "custom",
    .m_size = -1,
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_custom(void) {
    PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&custommodule);
    if (module == NULL)
        return NULL;

    MetaType.tp_base = &PyType_Type;
    if (PyType_Ready(&MetaType) < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(&MetaType);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "Meta", (PyObject *) &MetaType);

    if (PyType_Ready(&ParentType) < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(&ParentType);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "Parent", (PyObject *) &ParentType);

    return module;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The metaclass is nothing but *a type* that is used as *the type* (**`ob_type`**!) of the class (type)... (clear, isn't it)... `ParentType` does not inherit from `MetaType` but is an instance of `MetaType.

Hence, the place where `&MetaType` *should* go (if anywhere), is `ParentType.ob_type`:

```
PyModule_AddObject(module, "Meta", (PyObject *) &MetaType);

ParentType.ob_type = &MetaType;

if (PyType_Ready(&ParentType) < 0)
```

`PyType_Ready` checks the `ob_type` field - if it is `NULL`, it takes the `ob_type` of the `.tp_base`; but if `ob_type` is set already, it is left as is.

Actually you can set it in the `ParentType` initializer:

```
PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&MetaType, 0)
```

The first argument goes to the `ob_type` field.

Comment: It seems though the python source code has a special attribute called `PyId_metaclass` that it uses to determine the meta class .... https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9dfa0fe587eae3626ffc973680c6a17f35de3864/Python/bltinmodule.c#L151

Comment: @JoshWeinstein on the contrary, this is just the *string* `"metaclass"`, used to get the `metaclass=FooBar` from the kwargs.

Comment: Setting `ob_type` isn't going to be enough, though, because there are other problems with the code in the question. For example, `MetaObject` doesn't include a `PyTypeObject` base member, and `MetaType`'s `tp_base` needs to be set to `PyType_Type`.

Comment: Also, things like PyId_metaclass aren't *quite* just strings - they're wrappers used to manage interned, static strings. Python still ends up using it to fetch `metaclass` from the kwargs by string name, though. It's not any sort of special attribute, and it's not how the metaclass of an actual class object is stored.

Comment: Changing the `ParentType` struct to use `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&MetaType, 0)` (after fixing the [errors mentioned by user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957192/python-extension-in-c-metaclass#comment92824148_52957978)) causes a segfault. See the updated code

Comment: @Nelson: From a quick glance, you don't need the `PyObject_HEAD` in `MetaObject`; the `PyTypeObject`'s `PyObject_HEAD` takes care of that. There may be other problems. See the [relevant section](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html#subclassing-other-types) of the C API tutorial, and [`Modules/xxsubtype.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Modules/xxsubtype.c) for an example of implementing subclasses of built-in types in C.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way to do this. According to the [py docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html), there is no members or flags to directly indicate a class is a meta class of another. The attribute responsible for indicating a meta class is [inside the class dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__metaclass__#__metaclass__). You could implement something that modifies the `.tp_dict` member, but this is actually deemed [unsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dict) if done through the dictionary C-API.

> Warning It is not safe to use PyDict_SetItem() on or otherwise modify tp_dict with the dictionary C-API.

EDIT:

From the [python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9dfa0fe587eae3626ffc973680c6a17f35de3864/Python/bltinmodule.c#L151), it seems meta class is accessed as an `id` via the C dictionary API, but the methods to do so are prefixed with an `_`, and don't appear in any documentation.

```
    meta = _PyDict_GetItemId(mkw, &PyId_metaclass);
    if (meta != NULL) {
        Py_INCREF(meta);
        if (_PyDict_DelItemId(mkw, &PyId_metaclass) < 0) {
            Py_DECREF(meta);
            Py_DECREF(mkw);
            Py_DECREF(bases);
            return NULL;
        }
```

These methods are apart of the ["limited api"](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html), and can be used by defining the `Py_LIMITED_API` macro

```
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) _PyDict_GetItemId(PyObject *dp, struct _Py_Identifier *key);
#endif /* !Py_LIMITED_API */
PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyDict_SetItemString(PyObject *dp, const char *key, PyObject *item);
#ifndef Py_LIMITED_API
PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyDict_SetItemId(PyObject *dp, struct _Py_Identifier *key, PyObject *item);
#endif /* !Py_LIMITED_API */
```

Comment: There is a member indicating a class's metaclass; it's part of PyObject_HEAD, and it's the same member used for any other object's class. The `__metaclass__` dict entry isn't used in Python 3, and it was only ever used in Python 2 during class creation, not to determine the metaclass of an already-created class.

Comment: Setting `__metaclass__` in the dict of an existing class won't affect its metaclass. Also, messing with `tp_dict` after `PyType_Ready` is called is still unsafe.

Comment: Can you link to where that part of PyObject_HEAD is? not documented here https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject

Comment: /usr/include/python3.6/object.h:83 `#define PyObject_HEAD   PyObject ob_base;`. I don't understand how a `PyObject` contains the information about a type's metaclass

Comment: Updated my answer to include the place in the python source code that checks an objects meta class. It is *not* in `PyObject_HEAD`

Comment: @Nelson: That would be the `struct _typeobject *ob_type;` inside the [`PyObject` definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Include/object.h#L106), which records the type of an object. A class's metaclass is its type.

Comment: Also, defining `Py_LIMITED_API` is not required to access any part of the C API. Defining `Py_LIMITED_API` *restricts* you to a subset of the C API.